# Convert JsDefined to String

Tags: scala, playframework

I use play json library to process json objects in Scala. In order to get a field `id` from the json object, I run this code:

`val id = json \ "id"`

Then I want to convert `id` into a String. I tried `id.get.toString` but instead of `doi:10.1186-s13612-016-0045-3` I got `JsDefined("doi:10.1186-s13612-016-0045-3")`

How to convert it into a String?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
(json \ "id").as[JsString].value
```

Answer (score 10):

Slightly shorter:

```
(json \ "id").as[String]
```